# Why does Qrow attack Winter?

Tags: rwby

In RWBY Qrow attacks Winter

But I don't quite understand why and i'm sick of pure speculation. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

Qrow doesn't attack Winter. He *provokes* her, but she swings first (not counting the robots). It's explicit he's pissed off at Ironwood and is needling her to get her to start the fight to get in trouble and tick off Ironwood. And probably because it amuses him.